# How do i make the display fit?

Tags: css, reactjs, display

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDst8.jpg

How do i fix it?
I want to make it like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2Jfh.jpg

The first image is my website when i use normal mode / phone mode

The second image is my website when i use desktop mode in my phone

```
My css:
text-align: center;
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
      color: white;
```

Comment: Question is unclear, please add some code. It's difficult to understand your problem without seeing code

Comment: paste your HTML also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it look more like the first image, you need to specify a viewport (if you haven't already) before `</head>` with this code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

If you reload, you will probably see that it looks much better.

Next, you should also specify a max width in your CSS:

```
max-width: 90%;
```

You should also add a margin to the sides:

```
margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex: wrap;` to fix it,
and It can be done in many ways. you can explore the flex and grid properties in here,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS